Extracting continuous effects from a brms model after weighting using the marginaleffects package - avg_slopes() or slopes()?
I'd like to estimate the causal effect of the continuous variable perc_quality_plus_palms on the number of counts of different bird species for each combination of Forest.dependency (3 categories) and Trophic.Niche (4 categories; both are species-level properties). It is quite a complex hierarchical Bayesian model and I have conducted weighting beforehand:
brm(
  bf(CountVisit | weights(weights) ~ t2(perc_quality_plus_palms, Forest.dependency, Trophic.Niche, bs = c("cr", "re", "re")) + 
       (1 + perc_quality_plus_palms | name_latin) +
       (1 | square_ID / point_ID) +
       (offset(effArea2)),
     zi ~ perc_quality_plus_palms + (1|name_latin)
  ),
  data = birds.i,
  family = zero_inflated_poisson(),
  chains = 4,
  cores = 4,
  iter = 3000,
  warmup = 1000,
  prior = my_priors
)

I have been following this blogpost when I estimated the effect of perc_quality_plus_palms on different outcomes in a simple lm model (i.e. I've used avg_predictions and avg_slopes). However, I'm now unsure how I can assess (using the marginaleffects package) whether perc_quality_plus_palms has an effect along the perc_quality_plus_palms continuum for each forest dependency-niche combination.
I've tried following the logic of the blogpost and used avg_slopes (see below), however, from reading other information on the marginaleffects package I'm now not sure whether this is appropriate and whether I should be using slopes() instead?
Any insights on this would be immensely appreciated!
values <- with(birds.i, seq(quantile(perc_quality_plus_palms, .1),
                            quantile(perc_quality_plus_palms, .9),
                            length.out = 100))
avg_slopes(my_brm_wfh_splines_nichedep, newdata = datagridcf(perc_quality_plus_palms = values,Forest.dependency = "Medium", Trophic.Niche = "Frugivore", grid_type = "counterfactual"),variables = "perc_quality_plus_palms", by = "perc_quality_plus_palms", ndraws = 300, re_formula = NA, dpar = "mu")  


avg_slopes() returns the arithmetic mean of the individual slopes() -- it is literally the same function with an extra default for the by argument. Seems to me your question boils down to whether that's a good summary statistic of your parameter (posterior) and what the levels you want to marginalize over are.

How do weights feature in this analysis?

Thank you! I conducted weighting (using WeightIt; to ensure covariate balance along the perc_quality_plus_palms continuum) and included these weights in the brms model
